# What configurations do I need to enable on sshd_config to be able to use it as a jump node server?

Tags: ssh

What configurations do I need to enable on sshd_config on a jump node server to be able to utilize that server using ProxyJump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable port forwarding with [`AllowTcpForwarding`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-server/sshd_config.5#AllowTcpForwarding) using at least `local` or else `yes` (which is the default):

> Specifies whether TCP forwarding is permitted. The available options are `yes` (the default) or `all` to allow TCP forwarding, `no` to prevent all TCP forwarding, `local` to allow local (from the perspective of ssh(1)) forwarding only or `remote` to allow remote forwarding only.

That's because the `ProxyJump` option is just an optimized method (using pipes instead of tcp or unix sockets on the local side) from the client to ask the server to forward a tcp port. In the end the server is just receiving the same request and doing the same treatment.

Running:

```
$ ssh -J proxyhost destinationhost
```

currently spawns a subprocess (both are connected with two pairs of pipes for a full-duplex result):

```
ssh -W destinationhost:22 proxyhost
```

`-W` is an [ssh](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1) option similar to `-L`:

> ```
> -W host:port
> ```
>
> Requests that standard input and output on the client **be forwarded to host on port over the secure channel**. Implies `-N`, `-T`, `ExitOnForwardFailure` and `ClearAllForwardings`, though these can be overridden in the configuration file or using -o command line options.